# IIS rewrite with unusual ~ character in the URL

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, iis-8, iis-8.5

I have a URL in the format:

```
https://www.example.com/aaa/bbb/product/~productId=abc123
```

Which I would like to redirect to:

```
https://www.example.com/product/abc123
```

I have tried a couple of variations on this and just cannot get this to pick it up (despite testing this in the IIS URL rewrite regex tester).

```
<rule name="Custom rule 12" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="aaa/bbb/product/(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="~productId=(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/product/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rule.

```
            <rule name="specialcharacter" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="aaa/bbb/product/~productId=(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/product/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

Result:

[image]